# Virtual keyboard in TASM

Tags: assembly, x86-16, tasm, dosbox

I know it's quite a long-shot but I'm stuck in the middle of a school assembly project and as I'm pretty new to programming, I'm having a hard time tracking down the problem(s) in my code.

I'm trying to make an virtual (on-screen) keyboard. The values of the location of each button is found in 2 arrays, one for the X value of the center of the button, other for the Y.

Example arrays keyboard's top row:

```
x_arr dw 13,37,61,85,109,133,157,181,205,229
y_arr dw 113,113,113,113,113,113,113,113,113,113
```

The computer waits for a mouse click from the user and using an algorithm finds if or which button was pressed, then matches that button with an array of ascii values of each letter:

```
letter_arr db 81,87,68,82,84,89,85,73,79,80 ;QWERTYUIOP
```

My program doesn't seem to work. I'll add the full code and a picture of the keyboard itself.

Sorry if anything was bit messy. Thanks in advance!

[image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dnlq6.png)

```
IDEAL
MODEL small
STACK 0f500h
;---------------
MAX_BMP_WIDTH = 320
MAX_BMP_HEIGHT = 200
SMALL_BMP_HEIGHT = 40
SMALL_BMP_WIDTH = 40

DATASEG

    ;------Image related data------
    OneBmpLine db MAX_BMP_WIDTH dup (0)  ;One Color line read buffer
    ScreenLineMax db MAX_BMP_WIDTH dup (0)  ;One Color line read buffer
    FileHandle dw ?
    Header db 54 dup(0)
    Palette db 400h dup (0)
    SmallPicName db 'keyboar1.bmp',0
    BmpFileErrorMsg db 'Error At Opening Bmp File .', 0dh, 0ah,'$'
    ErrorFile db 0
    BB db "BB..",'$'     
    BmpLeft dw ?
    BmpTop dw ?
    BmpColSize dw ?
    BmpRowSize dw ?
    ;-----Program related data-----
    mouse_click dw ?
    letter_arr db 81,87,68,82,84,89,85,73,79,80         ;array containing ascii values of letters
    x_arr dw 13,37,61,85,109,133,157,181,205,229        ;array containing x value of center of buttons representing letters in letter_arr
    y_arr dw 113,113,113,113,113,113,113,113,113,113    ;array containing y value of center of buttons representing letters in letter_arr
    mouse_last_button dw 0  ;holds the value of last mouse button clicked
    mouse_button dw 1       ;holds the value of mouse button clicked

CODESEG

;================PROCEDURES================
;-----------------
proc OpenShowBmp near
    push cx
    push bx
    call OpenBmpFile
    cmp [ErrorFile],1
    je @@ExitProc
    call ReadBmpHeader
    ; from  here assume bx is global param with file handle. 
    call ReadBmpPalette
    call CopyBmpPalette
    call ShowBMP 
    call CloseBmpFile
@@ExitProc:
    pop bx
    pop cx
    ret
endp OpenShowBmp    
;-----------------
proc OpenBmpFile    near                         
;input dx filename to open  
    mov ah, 3Dh
    xor al, al
    int 21h
    jc @@ErrorAtOpen
    mov [FileHandle], ax
    jmp @@ExitProc  
@@ErrorAtOpen:
    mov [ErrorFile],1
@@ExitProc: 
    ret
endp OpenBmpFile

proc CloseBmpFile near
    mov ah,3Eh
    mov bx, [FileHandle]
    int 21h
    ret
endp CloseBmpFile
;-----------------
proc ReadBmpHeader  near                    
; Read 54 bytes the Header  
    push cx
    push dx

    mov ah,3fh
    mov bx, [FileHandle]
    mov cx,54
    mov dx,offset Header
    int 21h

    pop dx
    pop cx
    ret
endp ReadBmpHeader
;-----------------
proc ReadBmpPalette near
; Read BMP file color palette, 256 colors * 4 bytes (400h)
; 4 bytes for each color BGR + null)            
    push cx
    push dx

    mov ah,3fh
    mov cx,400h
    mov dx,offset Palette
    int 21h

    pop dx
    pop cx

    ret
endp ReadBmpPalette
;-----------------
proc CopyBmpPalette near                    
; Will move out to screen memory the colors
; video ports are 3C8h for number of first color
; and 3C9h for all rest                                 
    push cx
    push dx

    mov si,offset Palette
    mov cx,256
    mov dx,3C8h
    mov al,0  ; black first                         
    out dx,al ;3C8h
    inc dx    ;3C9h
CopyNextColor:
    mov al,[si+2]       ; Red               
    shr al,2            ; divide by 4 Max (cos max is 63 and we have here max 255 ) (loosing color resolution).             
    out dx,al                       
    mov al,[si+1]       ; Green.                
    shr al,2            
    out dx,al                           
    mov al,[si]         ; Blue.             
    shr al,2            
    out dx,al                           
    add si,4            ; Point to next color.  (4 bytes for each color BGR + null)             

    loop CopyNextColor

    pop dx
    pop cx

    ret
endp CopyBmpPalette
;-----------------
proc ShowBMP 
; BMP graphics are saved upside-down.
; Read the graphic line by line (BmpRowSize lines in VGA format),
; displaying the lines from bottom to top.
    push cx

    mov ax, 0A000h
    mov es, ax

    mov cx,[BmpRowSize]

    mov ax,[BmpColSize] ; row size must dived by 4 so if it less we must calculate the extra padding bytes
    xor dx,dx
    mov si,4
    div si
    mov bp,dx

    mov dx,[BmpLeft]

@@NextLine:
    push cx
    push dx

    mov di,cx  ; Current Row at the small bmp (each time -1)
    add di,[BmpTop] ; add the Y on entire screen

    ; next 5 lines  di will be  = cx*320 + dx , point to the correct screen line
    mov cx,di
    shl cx,6
    shl di,8
    add di,cx
    add di,dx

    ; small Read one line
    mov ah,3fh
    mov cx,[BmpColSize]  
    add cx,bp  ; extra  bytes to each row must be divided by 4
    mov dx,offset ScreenLineMax
    int 21h
    ; Copy one line into video memory
    cld ; Clear direction flag, for movsb
    mov cx,[BmpColSize]  
    mov si,offset ScreenLineMax
    rep movsb ; Copy line to the screen

    pop dx
    pop cx

    loop @@NextLine

    pop cx
    ret
endp ShowBMP
;-----------------
proc setGraphic
    ;sets graphic mode
    mov ax, 13h
    int 10h
    ret
endp setGraphic
;-----------------
proc initMouse
    ;initializes mouse
    mov ax, 0
    int 33h ;resets mouse

    mov ax, 1
    int 33h ;shows pointer
    ret
endp initMouse
;-----------------
proc initImage
    ;imports keyboard bitmap
    mov [BmpLeft],0
    mov [BmpTop],0
    mov [BmpColSize], 320
    mov [BmpRowSize] ,200
    mov dx,offset SmallPicName
    call OpenShowBmp
    ret
endp initImage
;-----------------
proc getMouseClick
    mov ax, [mouse_button] ;stores te value of the last state of the mouse
    mov [mouse_last_button], ax

    mov ax, 03h
    int 33h ;gets mouse information

    mov [mouse_button], bx ;saves the click inforamtion
    shr cx, 1 ;halves the x position value since the interrupt returns double
    ret
endp getMouseClick
;-----------------
proc checkMouseButton
    mov ax, [mouse_button]      ;waits for the user to click left mouse button
    cmp ax, 1
    jne mouseLoop

    cmp ax, [mouse_last_button] ;if button pressed before is the same as the current one,
    jne mouseLoop               ;skip the letter printing
    jmp doLoop
    ret
endp checkMouseButton
;-----------------
proc checkX 
    mov ax,cx   ;saves the x value of the click for later
    pop cx  ;pops the current value of counter to cx
    push ax
    mov si, offset x_arr
    add si,cx
    mov ax, [si]    ;moves the value at x array at index number cx (counter) to ax

    ;add ax, 9  ;checks if the click was inside a button range on x axis (9 pixels left and right of the center)
    pop cx
    cmp cx, ax
    ja mouseLoop

    mov ax, [si]
    sub ax, 9
    cmp cx, ax
    jb mouseLoop
endp checkX
;-----------------
proc checkY
    mov si, offset y_arr
    add si,cx
    mov ax, [si]

    sub ax, 9   ;checks if the click was inside a button range on y axis (9 pixels above and below the center)
    cmp dx, ax
    jb mouseLoop

    mov ax, [si]
    add ax, 9
    cmp dx, ax
    ja writeLetter
    ret
endp checkY
;-----------------
proc printLetter
    mov si, offset letter_arr   ;prints the letter whose ascii value matches the x and y values found previously
    add si,cx
    mov dl, [si]
    mov ah, 2h
    int 21h
    ret
endp printLetter
;-----------------
;================PROCEDURES================

start:
    mov ax,@data
    mov ds,ax

    call setGraphic ;sets graphic mode
    call initMouse ;initializes mouse
    call initImage  ;displays keyboard image

    mov cx, 10 ;iterates over all of the buttons in the keyboard until one matches a clicks location
mouseLoop:
    push cx
    call getMouseClick
    call checkMouseButton
    call checkX
    call checkY
    pop cx
    dec cx
    loop mouseLoop

writeLetter:
    call printLetter

doLoop: 
    mov cx,10 
    jmp mouseLoop

exit:
    mov ax, 4c00h
    int 21h
END start
```

Comment: Please include your code as code in a _code section_. Also include the image with the image button.

Comment: Coding style suggestion: use ASCII character literals instead of numeric constants, then you don't need a comment.  e.g. `letter_arr db "QWERTYUIOP"` or `letter_arr db 'Q', 'W', 'E', ...`

Comment: might be easier to check the pixel color instead of location

Comment: @Slai And how do I differentiate between each each button?

Comment: true, I didn't think of that. Maybe different shades of color, but from the screenshot seems like the color range might not be big enough for it to not be noticeable

Answer (score 2):

> ```
>  mov cx, 10 ;iterates over all of the buttons in the keyboard until one matches a clicks location
> mouseLoop:
>  push cx
>  call getMouseClick
>  call checkMouseButton
>  call checkX
>  call checkY
>  pop cx
>  dec cx
>  loop mouseLoop
> writeLetter:
>  call printLetter
> doLoop: 
>  mov cx,10 
>  jmp mouseLoop
> ```

This is your main program loop. Because they are procedures one would expect *getMouseClick*, *checkMouseButton*, *checkX* and *checkY* to return at the instruction below the `call`.

Only *getMouseClick* acts like a descent procedure!

But:

a. *checkMouseButton* jumps back to *mouseLoop* and to *doLoop*.
 b. *checkX* jumps back to *mouseLoop* and even thinks it pops `CX` where in fact it is popping the return address!
 c. *checkY* jumps back to *mouseLopp* and to *writeLetter*.

**None of these jump-backs removes the return address and the pushed `CX` off the stack**.

You need to re-think this entirely...

---

> ```
> dec cx
> loop mouseLoop
> ```

You know that `loop` already decrements the `CX` register. Why have a separate `dec cx` instruction?

Comment: When a procedure is ready to return the top element on the stack needs to be the return address. `ret` will pop it for you. If you push something __while you are IN the procedure__ you need to pop it beforehand. Your procedure should not try to remove things on the stack that were pushed by the caller like in the case of _checkX_.

Comment: So you're saying that skipping the ret command messes the stack?

Comment: If a procedure needs a value on the stack placed there by its caller, you can get it using: `proc checkX` `push bp` `mov bp, sp` `mov cx, [bp+4] ;CX pushed in mouseLoop` ...

Comment: A messed-up stack. That's what it is!